# How do I handle categorical data where there are different numbers of categories for a data point in training and testing?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am working on the following Kaggle project: https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques.

My question is, what if there is an option for a categorical value that is in the test data, but is not in the training data, or vice versa. For example, if data point A has options [a,b], in the training data, but options [a,b,c] in the testing data, or vice versa.  Thanks for your help!

I just want to be able to train and run my neural network properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you OneHotEncoding (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) your categorical data? You could avoid this problem by OneHotEncoding the categorical columns before splitting. This will mean that the model will be trained to consider this column. A drawback of this approach would that the training would only ever see '0' values for the column that represents the value which isn't seen in the training set. Maybe not the best option but could solve the issue you are seeing?

Is the issue caused by the fact that you have a very small dataset, or that you have a column that has lots of unique values?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping.  I was one-hot encoding but I would be open to other ideas.  The problem for this particular case is that the data set is small, but I would be curious about your answer for a column having lots of values as well?  Thanks!

Comment: I suspect one-hot encoding is the only way to deal with these columns, certainly if you are working with a small data set. You could perhaps consider duplicating your data population before dividing to increase the volume of your set? This would give you more to work with and if you directly duplicate the proportions of the attributes within the data set will be upheld.

Comment: Thanks!!  I'll definitely try that!